# Does it make a difference to use the GitHub app when integrating Xcode with GitHub?

Tags: xcode, github

My team is using GitHub with Xcode. We use the GitHub application for OS X to commit, branch and sync. The problem is that when two or more developers add files to the project, conflicts occur in the 'project.pbxproj' file. Recently I realized there is a commit/push/pull option in Xcode.

If I stop using the GitHub application and use Xcode's commit, push, pull and merge, would those conflicts in 'project.pbxproj' file stop occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still have conflicts.

If somebody makes a change to the project file and you make a change to the project file and you try to commit it at the same time as (or soon after) the other person, there's a good chance you'll see conflicts.

Thankfully, the "`project.pbxproj`" project file is text which can you can open with your favorite editor (`vi` or `emacs` or whatever) and you can resolve the conflicts rather easily.